# How to link svn hooks to checked out repository

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

How to link svn hooks to checked out repository?.
I have checked out a sample SVN repo. And with SVN-admin option, I created svn repo(?), which has sample hooks .
But how do I link my newly written script to work on local checked-out repo?. Its needed ,, as I have test the script locally before putting in admin area.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be some terminology-related confusion here.  If you check out a repository using `svn checkout`, what you have is not a repository.  It is a *working copy*.  You can't do repository operations (like `commit` or `branch`) to a working copy, only to a repository.

If you are trying to test hook scripts, you need to first [set up a repository on your local machine](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html).  You can either [make your local repo act as a mirror](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) of the "real" repo, or you can seed your local repo using a copy of your data.  To do the latter, the procedure looks something like this:

1. Use [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) to grab a snapshot of your "real" repo.  Using `export` instead of `checkout` is important, since `export` will not create the Subversion metadata folders that are normally present (this is important).
2. Use [`svn import`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) to load this tree into your local repository.

This will result in the HEAD of your local repository looking exactly like the HEAD of your "real" repo.  Your local repo won't have the full history since it's not a complete mirror, but it will have the same file and folder layout.  Most of the time, this is sufficient for the purposes of testing scripts.